# Adding Numbers to a Range

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm making a program where I can add an Integer sequence to a Range. I'm having trouble adding this values to the Range. It should run the method `addNodeAfter`, but it does nothing.

Then when I want to display the Range I get a `NullPointerException` one this line:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= manyNodes; i++){
```

Any tips?

### Main:

```
public class PDEMain {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter a start number: ");
            Integer startNum = input.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Enter end number: ");
            Integer endNum = input.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Enter increment: ");
            Integer increment = input.nextInt();

            Range obj = new Range(startNum, endNum, increment);
            System.out.println(obj);

            obj.display();
    }

}
```

### Range:

```
public class Range implements Cloneable {

    private Integer data; // holds the data
    private Range link; //holds the link
    Range head; //refers to head of linked list
    private Integer manyNodes;
    private Integer startValue;
    private Integer endValue;
    private Scanner input;

    public Range(Integer data, Range link){    
        this.data = data;
        this.link = link;
    }

    public Range(Integer data, Range link, Range head) {
        this.data = data;
        this.link = link;
        this.head = head;
        manyNodes++;
    }


    public Range(Integer start, Integer end,Integer increment){
        if(start == null){
            startValue = 0;
        }
        if(increment == null){
            if(start < end){
                increment++;
            }else{
                increment--;
            }
        }
        for (int i = start; i <= end; i+= increment){
            addNodeAfter(i);
            System.out.println(i);
        }

    }

    public Integer getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Integer data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Range getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(Range link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

    public Range getHead() {
        return head;
    }

    public void setHead(Range head) {
        this.head = head;
    }

    public void addNodeAfter(Integer element){

        this.link = new Range(element, this.link);

    }

    public void display(){
        Range cursor = head;

        for (int i = 1; i <= manyNodes; i++){ // NPE on this line
            System.out.print(cursor.getData() + " ");
            cursor = cursor.getLink();            
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

}
```

Comment: What lines are the exceptions at?

Comment: Where is your `display` method?

Comment: I just added the display method. I get the exception at the for loop.

Comment: Why do you hold a reference to the `head`. This looks like a linked list. If the head element is removed, you no longer point to the head, and you don't know that.

Comment: @azurefrog I get the exception at ' for (int i = 1; i <= manyNodes; i++)  '

Comment: Integer object should be compared by `compare` method.

Comment: You are not initializing `manyNodes` anywhere... You really should re-think this class, as you seem to be using the same type (`Range`) both for the individual nodes and the "management" of the linked list, and you are confusing yourself by this.

Comment: I was not go through all the code, but what is the expected output? For example, if input is 1, 10 and 2. Output is?

Comment: @PSglass The output would be 1, 3, 5, 7, 9

Comment: @JoeArcelay Ok, I thought so. Why did you write so much complicated code for this easy task?

Comment: @azurefrog Thanks! The program will not give me an exception now. Now I have to find out why the linkedlist is not filling up.

Comment: @PSglass Well I wanted to try to implement this program using a linked list instead of an array (I am most familiar with arrays). I guess I confused myself trying to figure out how to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined `manyNodes` as an `Integer`, not an `int`.  This means that its default value is `null`, not `0`, and you never set the value anywhere in your code.

When you try to loop using it as the control variable in your `display()` method, the JVM is going to throw an NPE when it tries to unbox the `null`.

A quick fix would be to change the type to `int`:

```
private int manyNodes;
```

This will solve the immediate NPE, but still not display anything, since you never actually increment `manyNodes` in the constructor you're calling. This means that the for-loop in your `display()` method falls through and never actually prints any of the data.

I would recommend getting rid of `head` and `manyNodes` altogether, and re-writing your `display()` method along the lines of:

```
public void display() {
    Range cursor = getLink();
    while (cursor != null) {
        System.out.print(cursor.getData() + " ");
        cursor = cursor.getLink();
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Note that this will output the data "backwards" because of the way you add things in this constructor:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Range obj = new Range(1, 10, 1);
    obj.display();  // prints 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
}
```

You might want to take a look at an [existing linked-list implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/LinkedList.java) to get a better idea how they are normally written.