# Adding a number in between a Range

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, linked-list

I have made a program that takes a user's input for start number, end number, and an increment. This is added to a `Range` (linked-list). I want to add a number that the user inputted to this `Range` and put the inputted number in between each number.

**Main:**

```
public class PDEMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a start number: ");
        Integer startNum = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter end number: ");
        Integer endNum = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter increment: ");
        Integer increment = input.nextInt();

        Range obj = new Range(startNum, endNum, increment);
        obj.display();

        System.out.print(" Enter 1 for take:\n "
                        + "Enter 2 for drop:\n "
                        + "Enter 3 for repeat:\n "
                        + "Enter 4 for interpose: ");
        Integer number = input.nextInt();

        if(number == 1) {
            obj.take();
        }

        if(number == 2) {
            obj.drop();
        }

        if(number == 3) {
            obj.repeat();
        }

        if(number == 4) {
            obj.interpose();
        }        
    }
}
```

**Range:**

```
public class Range implements Cloneable {

private Integer data; // holds the data
private Range link; //holds the link
private Range head; //refers to head of linked list
private Integer startValue;
private Integer endValue;
private Scanner input;

public Range(Integer data, Range link) {

    this.data = data;
    this.link = link;
}

public Range(Integer data, Range link, Range head) {
    this.data = data;
    this.link = link;
    this.head = head;
}


public Range(Integer start, Integer end,Integer increment) {
     if(start == null) {
        startValue = 0;
    }

     if(increment == null) {
        if(start < end) {
            increment++;
        } else {
            increment--;
        }
    }

    for (int i = start; i <= end; i+= increment) {
        addNodeAfter(i);  
    }
}

public Integer getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(Integer data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public Range getLink() {
    return link;
}

public void setLink(Range link) {
    this.link = link;
}

public Range getHead() {
    return head;
}

public void setHead(Range head) {
    this.head = head;
}
```

I have the following code for this `interpose` method:

```
public void interpose() {
    System.out.println("What number would you like to interpose? ");
    Integer answer = input.nextInt();

    Range cursor = head;

    for (int i = 0; i <= answer; i++) {
        System.out.print(cursor.getData() + " ");
        this.link = new Range(answer, this.link);
        cursor = cursor.getLink();     
    }
    System.out.print("New Range: ");
    display();
    modify();
    anotherRange();
}
```

I get a NullPointerException at `Integer answer = input.nextInt();`

Any tips on why I get this Exception and also if my logic is correct?

Comment: An `Integer` is not a primitive data type and is actually an object so you need to initialize it as an object `Integer answer = new Integer(input.nextInt());`

Comment: @JackWilliams: Absolutely the wrong choice; the variable should instead be declared as an `int`. Also, with an `Integer` variable, the value just gets autoboxed, and `new Integer` actually makes things slightly *worse* due to defeating the small integer cache optimization. In any case, it doesn't have any relation to the bug.

Comment: what is this 'input' variable in the interpose method scope?
I can see you initialize and used 'input' in your 'main' method, but it will not be recognized in your 'interpose' method.

Comment: Isn't this more or less what you've asked [a few hours ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34364453/adding-numbers-to-a-range)?

Answer (score 3):

Try to add `Scanner` class into `interpose()` method like this:

```
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
 Integer answer = input.nextInt();
```

Comment: Thanks! That now makes the program run. Now I just need to figure out how to make the numbers interpose.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions to where I can put the a specified number in between each number?

Comment: @Joe Arcelay I just saw the question can you explain more?